# How to use variable from resource another .cs file with "using"

Tags: variables, namespaces, using, c#

I was wondering how to get a variable equivalent from another .cs file with "using" statement.
Like

```
using (namespace here)
Output(A, 8);
```

and the file with (namespace here) would have

```
A = 3
```

would I be able to directly refer to the variable, or would I need to locate it some other way?

Comment: What language do you typically program in?

Comment: In a word, no.  That's just not now namespace/`using` constructs work.  You'll need to give more details about the actual underlying problem for us to really be able to provide a more C# way of doing this.

Comment: I am using C# and my problem is that I have a program that needs a port number to function.  I easily want to edit these numbers through variables because I have to use that number repeatedly.  I would like to store the variable in another file for ease of access.

Comment: @user1733537 Are the values changing at compile time, once at the start of the program, continually throughout the program, or what?  Is that number used just in one place, throughout the application, just in one section of the application, etc.?

Comment: OK, I want to have a file that contains something like              A = 1                                                               B = 2                                                               C = 3                                                               and then I would like to refer to those variables from another file.  But you said use class static properties, how would I do that?  The variables are being changed when I go to the file, or a program does, and edits them.

Comment: @user1733537: C#'s `using` statement is only very loosely connected to what `.cs` file anything is defined in. There is no reason to assume that two different `.cs` files would necessarily define their contents in two different *namespaces*, which is what is denoted by `using`. C#'s `using` is something entirely different from Pascal's `uses` statement in this respect.

Comment: OK. So I would define constants in a class other thatn in random variables.  I get it now.

Comment: Could you knid of do the same with function?  Like using mynamespace /*then call function*/ myfile.cs.myfunction(); ?

Comment: OK, but it says differently at Programmers Heaven.   http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/csharp/198061/198061/calling-a-function-in-another-file/

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to define a bunch of constant values in one location that can be used elsewhere this is the standard pattern you would follow:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const int MyFavoriteNumber = 3;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else you can have:

```
using MyNameSpace;
namespace MyOtherNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Constants.MyFavoriteNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically change the scope of a code like that. What an identifier is, is determined at compile time, so you can't change what it means at runtime.

Make a class or an interface that specifies what it is that you want to use from the different files, then inherit the class or implement the interface to make different implementations in different files. When you use one of the implementations you get the values from that file.

Example:

```
public interface ICommon {
  int A { get; }
}

public class File1 : ICommon {
  public int A { get { return 42; } }
}

public class File2 : ICommon {
  private int _value = 1;
  public int A { get { return _value; } }
}
```

Now you can use different objects:

```
ICommon x;
if (something) {
  x = new File1();
} else {
  x = new File2();
}

Output(x.A, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

.CS files contains *classes*, not *variables*.  If the .CS file contains a *class* that has a static property A you would just reference that static property:

```
Output(ClassName.A, 8);
```

Otherwise you need to provide more context as to what you *have* and what you're trying to *do*.